# What determines if I can use an object with the using function?

Tags: c#, dispose

For example:

```
using (disposable object here)
{

}
```

What determines if I can use an object in this way?

Would this work correctly?

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to be used in a [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) statement, a class needs to implement the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface.

In your example, [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) derives from [Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx), which implements `IDisposable`, so it would indeed work.

Comment: +1. An implicit conversion to `IDisposable` is also acceptable, as is an implicit *dynamic* conversion.

Comment: Not that it's useful, but **using (null) {}** works. I haven't bothered to find out why yet and not sure how I got into this bit of triviality.

Comment: @Kit, it works because the [C# spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) says: `If a null resource is acquired, then no call to Dispose is made, and no exception is thrown.`

Comment: Oh yeah. I forgot that. I guess my example is the canonical case to illustrate that!

Answer (score 1):

You can use it if the class implements the [`IDisposable` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aax125c9.aspx). This keyword is basically just syntactic sugar for calling the object's [`IDisposable.Dispose()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) method automatically after the `using` block.

The `Dispose()` method:

> Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 1):

The object provided in the using statement must implement the IDisposable interface.

This interface provides the Dispose method, which should release the object's resources.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It works if the object implements `IDisposable`.

[`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) inherits from [`Component`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx) which does implement `IDisposable` so your code should work.

If it didn't work you should get a compile time error.